# How to call a function at the same time as another ajax request - rails, javascript, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a pop out basket that gets updated via an AJAX call and that works perfectly.

I also have what i would call 'basket information' that just sits on the top of the page and displays the number of items in the basket and total cost. This information is contained in a cookie and is currently only updated when the page is reloaded. There are a couple of functions for this.

What i want is for that information to also change when the pop out basket is updated via the AJAX call.

Is this possible? Please help

**The view 1 (_mini_basket.html.erb):**

```
<div class="mini-basket-wrapper">
 #other code here
 <li>

    <%= image_tag order_item.product.product_images.first.src_url(:tiny_thumb) %>
    <%= link_to order_item.product.name, product_by_slug_path(order_item.product.slug)%>
    <span>x<%= order_item.quantity %></span>
    <%= link_to "Remove", basket_remove_path(:order_item => order_item), method: "delete", remote: true, class: "mini-basket-order-item-remove"%>

  </li>
</div>
```

**remove.js.erb**

```
$('div.mini-basket-wrapper').html("<%= j(render 'shop/baskorder/mini_basket') %>");
```

**controller**

```
  def remove

   order_item = params[:order_item].to_i

   if my_baskorder.order_items.collect(&:id).include? order_item
    my_baskorder.order_items.each do |oi|
     if oi[:id] == order_item
      my_baskorder.order_items.delete(oi)
     end  
    end  
   end 

   respond_to do |format|
    format.js
   end

 end
```

**The view 2:**

```
# i know document.write is not necessarily good practice


  <script type='text/javascript'>

    document.write(basket_text());

  </script>
```

**The JS:**

```
function fc_basket_text_from_cookie(empty_text, normal_text)
{
  var basket = readCookie('bk');

  if (basket)
  {
    var parts = decodeURIComponent(basket.replace(/\+/g, '%20')).split('|')

    if (parseInt(parts[1]) == 0)
      return normal_text.replace(/##VALUE##/g, parts[0]).replace(/##ITEMS##/g, parseInt(parts[1]));
      // return empty_text
    else
      return normal_text.replace(/##VALUE##/g, parts[0]).replace(/##ITEMS##/g, parseInt(parts[1]));
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

var emptyBasketHTML = "<span class='header_text'>Items in basket: 0 Total: &#163;0.00</span>";
function basket_text(){
  var populated = "<span class='header_text'>Items in basket: ##ITEMS##</span><span class='header_text'>Total: ##VALUE##</span>";
  //populated += "<input type='submit' value='Checkout' name='commit' class='go_botton header-checkout-button'>"
  return fc_basket_text_from_cookie(emptyBasketHTML,populated);

}
```

Comment: Why not call your function within the Ajax success function?

Comment: Or as your using a js.erb put your function call after your render

Comment: could you demonstrate please @Richlewis? Cheers

Comment: You don't need a function just put the code to update the cart icon right after the code for adding the items via Ajax

Comment: @www139 could you demonstrate what you mean please? cheers

Comment: @www139 anything? cheers

Comment: Now that I think about it I don't even think you will need to do any code. Just make the server side script return the number of items and then use the JQuery load to do it. I'll give the html modifications needed in my answer which should be posted shortly.

Comment: If i add the following to `remove.js.erb` it replaces the markup of the entire page with just the markup created by calling `basket_text()` markup

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Tell me if it does or doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
    function addItemToCart()
    {
      //gather new item information
      //make request and add item to database cart

      $.post("addItemToCart.php",
      {
       //cart information variables receive and insert into database or cookie with php
      },
      function(data, status){
         //this code runs then the request is complete:
         //update the number of items in the cart
         //you also want to call do this onload:
         $("#numberOfItemsInCart").load("getCartNumber.php");
      });
    }
```

HTML:

You have  items in the cart.

PHP getCarNumber.php:

```
<?php
//IF YOU HAVE A DATABASE:
//make sure you have customer id of some kind accessible here:
$customerId = /*get your customer id*/ "store id here";
//add your connect code
$query = "select * from itemsInCarts where customer_id='$customerId';
$result = mysql_query($query, $connectVariable);
$numberOfItems = mysql_num_row($result);
echo $numberOfItems;
//update the cookie with the number of items (you can change the time):
setCookie('numberOfItems', $numberOfItems, time+3600*24, '/');

//WITH COOKIES:
//get cookie with items and count them then echo them back to your main js/html file.
?>
```

Hope this helps. Again, if you don't understand it, or if you don't like it then please tell me :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm unclear as to how to use it to be honest. What would this, `whateveryouwanttoload.php`, look like? Also, the basket cookie gets updated as soon as the ajax request is successful.